# Poor estimation of the probability density function (pdf) close to boundaries

Tags: python, statistics

When estimating the pdf of values that are in [0, 1] using `stats.kde.gaussian_kde`, then if the values are uniformly distributed, `stats.kde.gaussian_kde` gives very poor results close to the boundaries (close to 0 and close to 1). See the code and picture below.

Is there any way to deal with this poor estimation close to the boundaries ?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import random
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [random.uniform(0,1) for _ in range(10000)]
linsp = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

nparam_density = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(X)
nparam_density = nparam_density(linsp)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.hist(X, bins=30, normed=True)
ax.plot(linsp, nparam_density, 'r-', label='non-parametric density (smoothed by Gaussian kernel)')
ax.legend(loc='best')
fig.savefig('pdf.png')
```

Comment: well, it is doing what you asked for, best smoothed approximation to a normal distribution.

Comment: If your model is wrong, use a different model...

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all. It (the red curve) gives very poor results close to the boundary regions (close to 0 and close to 1) when values are uniformly distributed (as in my example). I want an estimated pdf to be quite close to a line (at 1) when values are uniformly distributed. What kernel estimator other than `stats.kde.gaussian_kde` would provide this ?